# Can Neo4j Spatial Geoserver find the country, city given an ip address, if so, how to set up on nodes already created?

Tags: neo4j-spatial

I have some data in Neo4j with nodes having ip addresses as properties and I would like to get lat, lon (and city, country) data based on the ip address, similar to using geoip.dat. Can Neo4j Spatial give me this data? What are the steps to achieve this?

Comment: thanks, Tomaz, works a charm :-)

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j spatial does not support finding location based on ip. You must use an API designed for getting location off of IP , like http://freegeoip.net/.. you can try calling this API directly with cypher

```
MATCH (m:Entity)
CALL apoc.load.json("http://freegeoip.net/json/?q=" + m.ip) YIELD value
//return response
RETURN value
```